# How to mirror image files via command line?

Tags: command-line, image-processing, convert-command

What I want to do is very simple. I've a `file.png`, which I want to mirror, i.e. the result should be a "reflection" of the original image.

I know big tools like GIMP and InkScape can do that, but I'm hoping for a command-line utility, something like `convert` (which sadly doesn't seem to have such an option, or at least it's not mentioned in the `man` page).

Answer (score 82, accepted):

From quick reading of [this](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=10382),  apparently `convert` calls this option `-flop` for horizontal mirroring, and `-flip` for vertical. All I needed to do was

```
convert -flop input.png output.png
```

Comment: sudo apt-get install imagemagick

Comment: I have read something about changing `convert` to `magick`. So if something goes wrong, try `magick`.

Comment: If you get error `magick.exe: no images found for operation -flop at CLI arg 1 @ error/operation.c/CLIOption/5353.`, try `magick input.png -flop output.png`. It works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to overwrite in-place and you have a ton of image files in the same folder, `mogrify` from the ImageMagick suite seems to be the easiest way to achieve this:

```
# mirror in the vertical axis:
mogrify -flip *.jpg

# mirror in the horizontal axis:
mogrify -flop *.jpg
```

Comment: Note that mirroring horizontally (flopping) is actually reflecting in a vertical plane and mirroring vertically (flipping) is reflecting in a horizontal plane.

Answer (score 5):

For this particular task `convert` is probably the best way to go, but for this kind of thing I often use the `netpbm` library, which is installable (as you would expect) with `apt install netpbm`.  Then

```
  pngtopnm input.png | pnmflip -lr \
    | (other transformations if desired) \  
    | pnmtopng > output.png
```

For this task it's overkill, but I often find myself writing one-off scripts to transform or analyze PNM files in peculiar ways that wouldn't be available in `convert`.  This is relatively easy, because PNM is pretty much the simplest imaginable bitmap graphic format.